# How to have WebDriverWait look for a certain number

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I built a Auction monitor with selenium that has worked pretty much flawlessly since i started using it. The way it works is, it goes to a Property Auction site and monitors the price of the auction(pretty simple) and it alerts me via txt of `ANY` Changes in the price. The price it looks at varies because its not always a live auction it looks at, it also looks at the price of a auction that has ended to alert us of people who have dropped out of the auction and let us bid on it. What i need the script to do now is have it wait for a specific number and everything under that number. For example, if the price i want to wait for is `207,000`, Then the script would alert me of anything from 1-207,000 and nothing over that amount.

In my head it seems like a very simple thing to implement, But nothing comes to mind on how to do it.

Heres some of the code:

```
propertyprice = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
    currentBidText = propertyprice.text
    try:                                
        WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until_not(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-bid'), currentBidText)
            )
```

^ This is where it waits for the changes.

Comment: Is website URL private ?

Comment: No, its a public auction.

Comment: Can you share the URL ? I'll better have a look.

Comment: https://www.hubzu.com/property/900706107216-13610-Southwest-119-Street-Miami-FL-33186 , the price it would look at is after you click, "Place backup bid" , idk if you need to be registered to look at that

Comment: yeah, registration is required.

Comment: I can add in the html from where the number is if u'd like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193333/discussion-between-cruisepandey-and-reggie-jones).

Answer (score 0):

Use While loop to check continuous value from the desire element and compare with base bid price.Once it mismatch with base bid price it will exit from the loop.

```
propertyprice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
currentBidText = propertyprice.text
print(currentBidText)
while(True):
    NextBidPrice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid').text
    if not(NextBidPrice==currentBidText):
        print(NextBidPrice)
        break
    else:
        print('Awaiting for next bid.....')
```